# SQL (Firebird) query too slow

Tags: c#, sql, performance, firebird

Until now I made my program without any demanding functions, but then I made function that takes a lot of time. It is start of the fifth month of the year, and every day my database gets populated with more than 400 documents (each document has 5-7 items on average (5-7 new lines to the table `ROBA`). So after some time populating, it takes more and more time to calculate everything and I need to speed it up.

For now it takes about 60 sec to finish up everything. So I want to know if there is any way to speed this up, what to use, what to look for. Here is function I have:

```
private void ucitajStanje()
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        List<List_Int_Decimal> List_roba = new List<List_Int_Decimal>();

        using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString_PrirucniMagacin))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT ROBAID, KOLICINA FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = 0 AND BRDOK = 1", con))
            {
                FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (!(dr[0] is DBNull))
                    {
                        List_roba.Add(new List_Int_Decimal { ROBAID = Convert.ToInt16(dr[0]), kolicina = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]) });
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString_Baza))
        {
            con.Open();

            //Selektuje stanje u magacinu iz komercijalnog
            using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter("SELECT ROBA.ROBAID, ROBA.KATBR, ROBA.NAZIV, ROBAUMAGACINU.STANJE AS STANJE_KOMERCIJALNO FROM ROBAUMAGACINU INNER JOIN ROBA ON ROBAUMAGACINU.ROBAID = ROBA.ROBAID WHERE MAGACINID = 12 AND VRSTA = 1", con))
            {
                da.Fill(dt1);
            }

            //FIRST SLOW QUERY


            //izracunava stanje kartice robe bez pocetnog stanja iz komercijalnog gde se dodaje na stanje
            using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT ROBAID, SUM(KOLICINA) FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = 16 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 OR VRDOK = 18 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 OR VRDOK = 22 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 GROUP BY ROBAID", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Robaid", FbDbType.Integer);
                    foreach (var robaid in List_roba)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Robaid"].Value = robaid.ROBAID;

                    FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (!(dr[0] is DBNull))
                        {
                            int trenutnaRobaId = Convert.ToInt16(dr[0]);

                            var roba = List_roba.Where(r => r.ROBAID == trenutnaRobaId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (roba != null)
                            { roba.kolicina = roba.kolicina + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]); }
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }                    
            }

            //SECOND SLOW QUERY

            //izracunava stanje kartice robe bez pocetnog stanja iz komercijalnog gde se oduzima sa stanja
            using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT ROBAID, SUM(KOLICINA) FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = 15 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 OR VRDOK = 17 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 OR VRDOK = 19 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 OR VRDOK = 34 AND ROBAID = @Robaid AND MAGACINID = 12 GROUP BY ROBAID", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Robaid", FbDbType.Integer);
                foreach (var robaid in List_roba)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Robaid"].Value = robaid.ROBAID;

                    FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (!(dr[0] is DBNull))
                        {
                            int trenutnaRobaId = Convert.ToInt16(dr[0]);
                            var roba = List_roba.Where(r => r.ROBAID == trenutnaRobaId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (roba != null)
                            { roba.kolicina = roba.kolicina - Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]); }
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }                    
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        DataTable dt2 = StaticFunctions.ToDataTable(List_roba);

        var dt = new[] { dt1, dt2 };
        DataTable mergedDT = StaticFunctions.MergeAll(dt, "ROBAID");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = mergedDT;

        dataGridView1.Columns["ROBAID"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["KATBR"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns["NAZIV"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns["STANJE_KOMERCIJALNO"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["robaid"].Visible = false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: how many records are there in that table? You may create index on ROBAID.

Comment: That is very small amount. I do not use FireBird and not sure about its performance. If you can, add Index on ROBAID and try again.

Comment: Table `ROBA` contains 4890 rows, In table `stavka` there is 312978

Comment: That is not large. I forgot to ask do you mean the actual query is slow or foreach is slow?

Comment: @wannadream ok so i think i have index on it (http://prnt.sc/f4bi6p) i think, but how to use it?

Comment: If it is indexed, it will improve the query performance automatically.

Comment: Additionally to all the answers, if your database would really grow fast, then perhaps you would have to make calculating and storing intermediate totals in the database. Say, you can not re-calculate sum of all and every numbers now and then, but have the table which would cache the once-computed and never again changed SUM results for like 2015 year, 2016 year, 207 January, 2017 Feb, 2017 March. That way you only compute individual records for current and previous months, and you ASSUME that any records that are more than a month old would never be adjusted, so you sum them once forever

Comment: Of course IF the assumption fails and you would retroactively correct more old records then "this month and prior month" - then you would have to be careful to DROP the cache before correction and RECALCULATE the cache when need it again. This would make your logic more complex and all the assumptions and usecases clearly documented (any cache does require it). You would probably have to use SQL Triggers to target and destroy proper cache segments. You would also have to make difference between "no data no cache" and "there is data but cache is invalidated" cases.

Comment: I'd use records like ( 2015, NULL ) or (2016 September, NULL ) to indicate there HAS to be some data, just it was invalidated. Then before make Grand Total you just check if there are NULL values in cache and recalculate those exactly values.  And if you want for a really load complex solutions - then try to fire www.translate.ru at  http://www.sql.ru/forum/964534/hranimye-agregaty-bez-konfliktov-i-blokirovok-recept - there is much more elaborate scheme, that you do not need right off, but just grokking its existence would add to your skillsets toolbox

Comment: "FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = 0 AND BRDOK = 1" - you do not have indices on those fields though. It is not also that index ALWAYS accelerates, there are corner cases. But the rule of thumb of course is one usually better have one than not. However if you are anticipate or see heavy work on some tables - then you better learn about indexings cons and pros in some firebird/interbase faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try avoiding to call query in a *loop* (i.e. performing the sql *again and again*):

```
  //FIRST SLOW QUERY

  // Loop! 
  foreach (var robaid in List_roba) {
    ...
    // Antipattern: Many a time query calling 
    FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ...
  }
```

Instead, execute query just *once*, in *one go*:

```
 //FIRST SLOW QUERY (Hope, much faster now)

 //DONE: Keep SQL readable
 string sql = 
    @"SELECT ROBAID, 
             SUM(KOLICINA) 
        FROM STAVKA 
       WHERE MAGACINID = 12 AND
             VRDOK IN (16, 18, 22)
    GROUP BY ROBAID";

 using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(sql, con)) {
   using (FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
     while (dr.Read()) {
       if (dr.IsDBNull(0)) // <- Is it really possible for Id to be null?
         continue;

       int trenutnaRobaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);

       //TODO: you may want to turn List_roba into Dictionary_roba:
       // if (Dictionary_roba.TryGeValue(trenutnaRobaId, out roba)) 
       //   roba.kolicina = roba.kolicina + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]);
       var roba = List_roba
         .Where(r => r.ROBAID == trenutnaRobaId)
         .FirstOrDefault();

       if (roba != null)  
         roba.kolicina = roba.kolicina + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]);
     } 
   }
 }
```

**Edit:** you can increase performance further if you turn `List_roba` into a *dictionary* (or at least, create a temporary dictionary), e.g.

```
 // In general case, if ROBAID can have duplicates
 var Dictionary_roba = List_roba
   .GroupBy(item => item.ROBAID)
   .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                 chunk => chunk.First());

 // If ROBAID is unique:
 //var Dictionary_roba = List_roba
 //  .ToDictionary(item => item.ROBAID, item => item); 

 ...

 using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(sql, con)) {
   using (FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
     while (dr.Read()) {
       if (dr.IsDBNull(0)) // <- Is it really possible for Id to be null?
         continue;

       int trenutnaRobaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);

       // C# 7.0 Syntax - out var; 
       // if you don't have C# 7.0 you have to declare "roba" variable  
       if (Dictionary_roba.TryGeValue(trenutnaRobaId, out var roba))
         roba.kolicina = roba.kolicina + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[1]);
     } 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm i get everything expect i need to select with condition `cmd.Parameters["@Robaid"].Value = robaid.ROBAID;`. Where do i add it if i use it like that?

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic: I suggest *combining* all the `ROBAID` in one query (that's why I've elimineted `@Robaid` parameter). Then we scan the cursor and if we have corresponding item in the `List_roba` we'll update it

Comment: Ok. It is much, much faster (it takes 2 sec now), but for last question what is difference between Dictionary and List in performance and what am i getting with that commented line under TODO?

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic: the query is now *fast*, but the collection is *not*: you have to *scan* the enire list - O(N) and in case of dictionary you just get the value - O(1). Turning `List<T>` into `Dictionary<K, V>` let you further performance increase

Comment: "<- Is it really possible for Id to be null?" judging by the screenshot made by the topic starter in comments above, RobaID is the primary key and AFAIR primary keys can not be all-NULLs in Firebird. IF RobaID was merely unique index rather than primary key, then NULL could be there and even several NULL rows.

Comment: Additionally, i'd perhaps try to loop over the list and then re-query server about specific "Robaid" values, opening the same pre-prepared query several times with different parameters. SOMETIMES it can be faster (but most probably not this time). And at very least it would be less RAM-consuming. Just to think out of the box.

Comment: @Arioch 'The: it seems that `Robaid` is unique (or, at most, have few duplicates) within the list; that's why looping the list will result in many queries which will flood the rdbms as well as the network.When working with (400 documents * 5-7 lines) ~ 2k-3k records, RAM is not a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your time. Dimitrys solution was enough to speed it up about 60 times.

Comment: @AleksaRistic - it is good a the moment, but what would you do three years later, when it would be no more enough ? Rush to Stack Overflow crying "help me" ? Well, sometimes it helps, sometimes not... So, you already hit performance bottleneck and i think it is worth starting thinking into the future preparing for the next crisis ahead of time.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Robaid is unque of course, otherwise trying to feed it into a dictionary you would get the feedback. Because in your .ToDictionary i see no folding functions, that if C# even knows about implicit auto-folding of lists with duplicates. And here, since meeting non-listed values we do not through them away but add them to the list, it would probably be like you said. However if we would query only for values on the list and ignore values non-listed it coud be different

Comment: Still, then - in the "only listed ones" case - the better options perhaps would be using a per-transaction Global Temporary Table, putting there those listed IDs of interest, and then JOINing your query against it.
Yet another approach would be getting a sorted list (or sorting it) instead of a dictionary, adding `ORDER BY RobaID` to your query, and then doing a one pass kind of a streaming sort. Frankly, if the List_roba is pre-sorted that would perhaps be the most efficient approach.

Comment: @Arioch 'The: adding values into list instead of throwing them away when `ROBAID` is not found can well be reasonable, but it changes current business logics (we udpate existing items with records from RDBMS). We don't even know the `List_roba` items' *class* (i.e. how can we create a new item). As for per-transaction temporary table we still have no info to think over; it can well appear a further improvement as well as a hole in the head. In my answer I've pointed out evident problems: query in the loop (the main source of disappointment) and list/dictionary as a collection choice.

Comment: @Arioch 'The: I totally agree with you that the current design wants revision, but I can't suggest its better version since I have no data